# Proof of a basic theorem in Algebraic topology course related to homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am taking an  course in Algebraic topology, and unfortunately, I'm unable to understand some proofs.

So, I am asking it here.

> Prove that following conditions on a space $X$ are equivalent:

(i) The identity map of $X$ is null homotopic.

(ii) For every $Y$, every map $h: Y \to X$ is null homotopic.

So, for (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii), let $i: X\rightarrow X$ is identity map and is given homotopic to $c$, which implies there exists an homotopy $\{h_t\}$ such that $h_0 = i$ and $h_1= c$. But how to show that for every $Y$, every map $h:Y \rightarrow X$ is null homotopic.

Converse , I proved taking $Y=X$ in (ii).

So, can you please help me with (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)?

Comment: $i \circ h = h$.

Comment: Think about composing functions in order to build the needed homotopy using the homotopy you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint spelling out the desired nullhomotopy in detail.

Let $F:X \times I \to X$ be a homotopy with $F \mid_{X \times \{0\}}=Id_X$ and $F \mid_{X \times\{1\}}=c_x$, where $c_x:X \to X$ is a constant map $c_x(z)=x$ for all $z \in X$.

Let $g:Y \to X$ be an arbitrary continuous map.
Then define $G:Y \times I \to X$ by $G(y,t)=F(g(y),t)$.

This is a nullhomotopy from $g$ to a constant map.

Comment: If you're having troubles showing the last sentence, leave  a comment and I'm happy to help.